# splitting string in a file and saving the values in an array is printing wrong output

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers, scanf

I am reading input from a file and storing them in an array.
I am splitting the name and the ages in a separate dynamic array since I don't know how long the input file could be.
However when I try to print out the string and the age , I get weird output and a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max 100

int main(){
  char *lines = malloc(max*sizeof(char));

    char **names = malloc(max*sizeof(char));
    int *ages =malloc(max*sizeof(int));

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("config2.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open filelist.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
int i= 0;
    while (i < max && fgets(lines, sizeof(lines), fp) != NULL) {
        sscanf(lines, "%s %d", names[i], &ages[i]);
        printf("%d", ages[i]);
        printf("%s", names[i]);

        i++;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Felix         9
Jonathan  50
Felix         18
Jonathan  50
Felix         90
Jonathan  50
Felix         24
Jonathan  50
Felix         76
Jonathan  50
Felix         56
Jonathan  50
Felix         21
Jonathan  50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
char **names = malloc(max*sizeof(char));
```

`names` is of `char**` type i.e you need to allocate memory for `names` first which you did above and then you need to allocate memory for `names[row]` which you didn't, that's why when this

```
sscanf(lines, "%s %d", names[i], &ages[i]);
```

executed it causes segmentation fault as no memory was allocated for `names[i]`.

Also what could be `sizeof(lines)` ? It's just `4` byte on `32` bit system. Change it to `MAX_LENGTH` where `MAX_LENGTH` is nothing but max length of line in a file.

```
while (i < max && fgets(lines, MAX_LENGTH, fp) != NULL) { /* read MAX_LENGTH char from file and store into lines */
        names[i] = malloc(MAX_LENGTH); 
        sscanf(lines, "%s %d", names[i], &ages[i]);
        printf("%d", ages[i]);
        printf("%s", names[i]);

        i++;
    }
```

And at the end when usage is done, don't forgot to free the dynamically allocated memories to avoid memory leakage.